# Is Google Adwords keyword tool showing right data like local monthly searches?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-ads

For example, for keyword `gifts`, keyword tool from Google shows Global Monthly Searches as 16,600,000 and (India) Local Monthly Searches as 823,000 so is it really a right numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Broad match type (on the left hand side). Try running the query with Phrase match type which will give you more realistic numbers.

Comment: To clarify: "broad match" includes synonyms and longer queries, "phrase match" includes longer phrases with the word, "exact match" is searches for just that word.  I always use exact match **only**.